# Trigger Not working

Tags: trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger to automatically calculate average industry prices automatically whenever we capture a quote from vendors.  Here's my trigger code below:

```
trigger UpdateAverageIndustryPrice on Purchase_Quote_Line__c (after insert) {

List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();
List<Purchase_Quote_Line__c> quoteList = new List<Purchase_Quote_Line__c>();
Double sumExchangePrice = 0, sumOutrightPrice = 0;
Integer exchangeCount = 0, outrightCount = 0;

for (Purchase_Quote_Line__c pq: Trigger.new){       
    idList.add(pq.Product__r.id);
    System.debug('Adding Product to List. Id: ' + pq.Product__r.id);
}

Integer size = idList.size();

for (Integer i=0; i < size; i++){
    quoteList = [select Id, Unit_exchange_Price__c, Unit_Outright_Price__c, Product__c 
                    from Purchase_Quote_Line__c 
                    where Product__c = :idList[i]
                    and CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:180];

    Integer quoteSize = quoteList.size();
    System.debug('Size of quote size '+ quoteSize);
    System.debug('Sum Exchange is '+sumExchangePrice+ ' Sum Outright is '+sumOutrightPrice);

    for(Integer j=0;j < quoteSize; j++){
        Product2 tempProduct = new Product2();
        tempProduct.id = quoteList[j].Product__c;
        System.debug('Quote Product is ' + quoteList[j].Product__c );
        System.debug('j count is: ' + j);

        System.debug('exchange Price is '+ quoteList[j].Unit_Exchange_Price__c);
        if(quoteList[j].Unit_Exchange_Price__c != 0){
            sumExchangePrice += quoteList[j].Unit_Exchange_Price__c;
            exchangeCount += 1;
            System.debug('exchangeCount is: ' + exchangeCount);
        }           

        System.debug('Outright Price is '+ quoteList[j].Unit_Outright_Price__c);
        if(quoteList[j].Unit_Outright_Price__c != 0){
            sumOutrightPrice += quoteList[j].Unit_Outright_Price__c;
            exchangeCount += 1;
            System.debug('outrightCount is: ' + outrightCount);
        }

        if(j == quoteSize-1 && exchangeCount != 0 && outrightCount != 0){
            tempProduct.Average_Exchange__c = sumExchangePrice/exchangeCount;
            tempProduct.Average_Outright__c = sumOutrightPrice/outrightCount;

            update tempProduct;
        }
    }

    sumExchangePrice = 0; sumOutrightPrice = 0;
    exchangeCount = 0; outrightCount = 0;
}
```

}

It looks like there are two conditional statements that it's not going into to sum up the prices.  Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

So I added some System.debug code into the trigger, but now when I execute anonymous, the trigger is not triggering.  Here's the code i'm using:

```
Product2 newProduct = [select id, Name, ProductCode from Product2 where id = '01tU0000000cDPH'];

Purchase_Request__c request = new purchase_request__c();
insert request;

Purchasing_quote__c quote = new purchasing_quote__c();
quote.purchase_request_number__c = request.id;//required
insert quote;

purchase_quote_line__c quoteLine = new purchase_quote_line__c();
quoteLine.purchase_quote_number__c = quote.id;//required
quoteLine.product__c = newProduct.id; 
quoteLine.unit_exchange_price__c = 100;
quoteLine.unit_outright_price__c  = 100;

insert quoteLine;
```

Comment: can you system.debug and see what the quoteList size is (ie) system.debug("Size of quote list"+quotelist.size()); see if the query returns any rows to start with

Comment: I also see that you are running a query inside a for loop (bad practice)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on SOQL in for loops.  I'll work on restructuring the code once I'm able to get the trigger working.

Comment: Can we see your test class?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `System.debug` statements is your best way to figure out why the if statements are not resolving to true. The issue may be data dependent in which case no one on here will be able to help. Here is the debugging I would start out with to figure out whats going on:

```
for (Purchase_Quote_Line__c pq: Trigger.new){ 
    System.debug('Adding Product to List. Id: ' + pq.Product__r.id);      
    idList.add(pq.Product__r.id);
}
System.debug('List size: ' + idList.size());
...
System.debug('Unit_Exchange_Price__c: ' + Unit_Exchange_Price__c);
if(quoteList[j].Unit_Exchange_Price__c != 0){
...
System.debug('Unit_Outright_Price__c: ' + Unit_Outright_Price__c);
if(quoteList[j].Unit_Outright_Price__c != 0){
```

As @rao pointed out in the comments, you have a SOQL statement in a for loop so your code wont be able to handle large batches of data. You should consider refactoring it.